# Show content while resize in chrome?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

As a web developer  -  I need to test how things(layout) change in real time When Im resizing the screen width/height

However this isn't working  as desired:

[image]

Is there any solution/plugin to do that ?

Desired result : while resizing  - see the content. ( not only when release mouse)

Comment: There is an effect in Windows named "Show contents when moving or resizing windows". If that is disabled you can't view contents when resizing or moving a window. Sometimes that will be disabled to increase system performance. Check it.

Comment: @Tom You're the man. yes - > the settings was "best performance" so it's unchecks it all :-) please post it as an answer.

Comment: If you have this issue in Lubuntu, run obconf from terminal and select Update Window Contents While Resizing under the Move and Resize tab.

Comment: I agree that @Tom is the man, however, I am in the future and in the future the setting is called "Show window contents while dragging". Once that was checked it started updating while resizing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an effect in Windows "System Properties" named "Show contents when moving or resizing windows". If that is disabled you can't view contents when resizing or moving a window. Sometimes that will be disabled to increase system performance. Check it.

Assuming Windows 7:

1. Click "Start"
2. Right click "Computer"
3. Click "Properties"
4. Click "Advanced system settings"
5. From the "Advanced" tab click "Settings" button under "Performance"
6. Select "Adjust for best performance" and click "Apply" (your screen will adjust, be patient)
7. Select "Let Windows choose what's best for my computer" and click "Apply" (your screen will re-adjust, be patient)
8. Click "OK" to close the System Properties window
9. Click "OK" to close the parent System Properties window and return to your desktop
10. Close all your Chrome browser windows
11. Re-open your Chrome browser windows and test to confirm the problem is fixed.